# Do duplicate materia combos work?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-rebirth

In [final-fantasy-7](/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7) you could add duplicate materias with different blue support materias to combine the effects. Now I have the equipment I have the possibility to try it.

On Aerith I have

```
[Magic Efficiency]-[Healing]
[Auto-cast]-[Healing]
```

[image: ff7 rebirth materia panel showing two linked slots of blue and green materia]

Does this mean that Aerith will auto-cast Cura at reduced MP cost? Or is this feature not part of [final-fantasy-7-rebirth](/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7-rebirth) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems this feature is available in Rebirth.

I equipped Aerith with the following...

```
[Magic Efficiency]-[Healing]
[Magnify]-[Healing]
```

and was able to cast Magnified Cura for 11mp instead of 14mp.

[image: UI showing magnified cura for 11mp]

**NB,** This *specific* combo only works in battle, due to the Magic Efficiency materia only working during battle.